# What's the variable for the current value of the slider at any given timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, round-slider

What would the variable for the current value of the roundSlider jquery plugin at any given time be called and how would I store this in my own variable?
http://roundsliderui.com/

Comment: Did you read their [documentation?](http://roundsliderui.com/document.html) They list the value there.

Answer (score 0):

Just use its getValue() method -

```
sliderValue = $('#slider').getValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the document from here:
http://roundsliderui.com/document.html#getValue

Also at anytime you can get the value like below:

```
var currentValue = $("#slider").roundSlider("getValue");
```